# Get a text with <br /> tag in a div with children using xpath until another children tag

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, xpath

i have a html code like:

```
        <span class="content_font">
        Shinta Geby, salah satu pendatang baru di dunia musik ingin kembali menghidupkan lagu 'Tinggal Kenangan' milik Geby yang sempat populer beberapa waktu lalu.<br /> <br /> Pemilik nama asli Shita Faula E itu mengemas lagu tersebut dengan gitar yang dimainkannya sendiri. Maklum, Shinta memang piawai dalam memetik gitar.<br /> <br /> "Lagu itu membuat saya lebih modern dalam berkarir. Jadi kenapa nggak mencoba dengan lagu itu, ternyata teman teman saya di media sosial kagumi saya bawakan lagu itu," ujar Shinta, Rabu (17/7/2013).<br /> <br /> Perempuan kelahiran 1 Desember 1995 itu juga mengaku tetap optimis meski hanya mendaur ulang lagu tersebut. Shinta yang mengidolai Tantri 'Kotak' mengaku aransemen 'Tinggal Kenangan' ini lebih ngerock dan fresh.<br /> <br /> "Saya percaya diri dalam karier saya. Ini yang membuat saya bisa perfomance di atas panggung," lanjut Shinta yang pernah tampil di 'Warna' Trans 7 itu.<br /> <br /> Usianya yang masih muda juga tak membuatnya ragu untuk terus berkarier di dunia hiburan. Shinta yang tadinya masih duduk di bangku SMA itu rela meninggalkan sekolahnya sejenak demi fokus menjadi penyanyi.<br /> <br /> "Persaiangan menjadi musisi di jagad hiburan sekarang nggak mudah, saya harus bisa melihat sisi positifnya. Yang terpenting saya diterima baik dulu oleh penggemar," kata Shinta yang masih ingin melanjutkan pendidikannya nanti.<br /><br />(kmb/doc)<br /> <br />

        <br />

        <!--S:SHARE BOX-->
        <div class="social_mp">
            <a href="http://m.detik.com/music/shareemail/2013/07/17/204024/2306214/228/shinta-geby-ingin-hidupkan-kembali-lagu-tinggal-kenangan"><img class="img_nobor" src="http://us.detik.net.id/mobileportal/image/email.png"alt="" width="80"  /></a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?t=Shinta+Geby+Ingin+Hidupkan+Kembali+Lagu+%27Tinggal+Kenangan%27&u=http://m.detik.com/music/read/2013/07/17/204024/2306214/228/shinta-geby-ingin-hidupkan-kembali-lagu-tinggal-kenangan"><img class="img_nobor" src="http://us.detik.net.id/mobileportal/image/facebook.png" alt="" width="80"  /></a>
            <a href="http://m.detik.com/?fa=detik.sharetwitter&s=Shinta+Geby+Ingin+Hidupkan+Kembali+Lagu+%27Tinggal+Kenangan%27&u=http://m.detik.com/music/read/2013/07/17/204024/2306214/228/shinta-geby-ingin-hidupkan-kembali-lagu-tinggal-kenangan&r=detikmusic"><img class="img_nobor" src="http://us.detik.net.id/mobileportal/image/twitter.png" alt="" width="80" /></a>
        </div>
        <!--E:SHARE BOX-->
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
        <!--S:KOMENTAR BOX-->
        <a href="http://m.detik.com/music/comment/form/2013/07/17/204024/2306214/228/shinta-geby-ingin-hidupkan-kembali-lagu-tinggal-kenangan">Send Comment</a> |
        <a href="http://m.detik.com/music/comment/2013/07/17/204024/2306214/228/shinta-geby-ingin-hidupkan-kembali-lagu-tinggal-kenangan">Read Comments (0)</a>
        <!--E:KOMENTAR BOX-->
        </span>
```

How can i only want to get all of the content before div class="social_mp",
what xpath should i use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given there is only one of those `<div/>`s:

```
//span[@class='content_font']/div[@class='social_mp']/preceding-sibling::node()
```

Select the terminating `<div/>` and select all preceding siblings. Change to `div[@class='social_mp'][1]` if multiple of those <`div/>`s could occur and you want to stop at the first one.

Comment: This returns all nodes until the div you've given, the XPath is definitely correct. The problem must be in the code around XPath - it will return some kind of sequence / array; I do not know .net's XPath interface, but probably you'll have to loop over the XPath result.

Comment: actually i using HTML agility pack for dot.net, and i am able to fix this by combining Jens Erat answer with a little looping.